# Required iPhone screen recording

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

Is there any app available that can record the screen of my iPhone. Is this possible in iOS to create such type of an app. If possible then what i have to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/ to record the screen from your MAC.

Comment: If you use wifi connect Airplay and it lags. Try to turn of your Mac wifi and use Personal Hotspot from iPhone share to your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AirServer (http://www.airserver.com) to mirror the display  from your iPhone to your Mac and then use QuickTime to record the screen and eventually export it as a movie.

If you want to try building something yourself, you can as well try using DisplayRecorder source. You can download the source from http://displayrecorder.net/

However, I do not think you can upload anything like that to the App Store, since Apple possibly won't allow you to record other apps.