# Screen video Recording ios

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to record iPhone screen real time playing video , I found "RecordMyScreen" demo app. But this demo app not working on IOS 7, it showing  black screen for video.Also I tested "ScreenCaptureView" app ,but it not working on for video capturing.
Can you please suggest me ,how I can record my screen or give me any links for the same 
  Thank you very much!

Comment: Helpful links :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19396101/required-iphone-screen-recording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to record in-game video, look at [EveryplaySDK](https://everyplay.com/about).

Comment: thannks for replay ,
i want to record real time screen recording on iphone device with out using any camera .

Comment: You can record screen only, without camera.

Comment: ok , But I am not recording in game app, I am developing native iphone app

Comment: If you want record video only once, as demo video for example, you can try [Reflector](http://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector/). There is no need to to embed sdk into application.